# how to create a 2D array in numpy another way?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have created a 2D array with numpy and pandas as below:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd 

data = np.array([['','A','B','C'],
            ['0','1','2','3'],
            ['1','4','5','6'],
            ['2','7','8','9']])

print(pd.DataFrame(data=data[1:,1:],
              index=data[1:,0],
              columns=data[0,1:]))
```

My question is that are there any other simpler way to create a 2D array in numpy and use pandas to put it into dataframe?

Comment: What do you mean by an easier way to create a numpy array?

Comment: And yeah, don't put your columns and index into the same array of course. Usually data is numeric and columns are text. Index is often numeric but of a completely different type than the data. They don't belong together.

Comment: @MadPhysicist What i mean is that when I have more data to input (sure there will be another way to do this when you have for example 1000000 data), i don't want to type like shown. So that I want to ask for a simpler way to get the same output

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
In [131]: data = np.arange(1,10).reshape(3,3)
In [132]: data
Out[132]: 
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [4, 5, 6],
       [7, 8, 9]])
In [133]: df = pd.DataFrame(data=data, columns=['A','B','C'])
In [134]: df
Out[134]: 
   A  B  C
0  1  2  3
1  4  5  6
2  7  8  9
In [135]: df.dtypes
Out[135]: 
A    int64
B    int64
C    int64
dtype: object
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you do not need to assign the `index` since it is from `0` to `len(df)`, also using the `numpy array` with mix data type will cause problem , since you output data type is `object` not int

```
pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,4,7],'B':[2,5,8],'C':[3,6,9]})
Out[1104]: 
   A  B  C
0  1  2  3
1  4  5  6
2  7  8  9
```

Comment: Good answer ;) But how to get from `data` to the dict?

Comment: @RafaelC IIUC *any other simpler way to create a 2D array in numpy * is he need a new way for creating the dataframe ?

Comment: Not sure wen.. I think he wants to create a data frame from `data` in a simpler way than using `pd.DataFrame(data=data[1:,1:], index=data[1:,0], columns=data[0,1:])`

Answer (score 1):

Or an direct list:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> pd.DataFrame([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]],columns=list('ABC'))
   A  B  C
0  1  2  3
1  4  5  6
2  7  8  9
>>>
```